# Prohibit Email Address from Street Address Field

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to simply prohibit the "@" from being entered into the Street Address field in my form.  I have the following code which stops "@" from being accepted, but just the character only.  I need it to create the error message if any use of "@" is included in the field (for example 'abc@123.com').
Thanks!

```
if (theForm.BillAddress.value == "@")
{
alert("Please enter your Billing Address not Email Address.");
theForm.BillAddress.focus();
return (false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're doing an exact match, change it to

```
if(theForm.BillAddress.value.indexOf("@") != -1)
```